# How to validate my select forms in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm creating a multi step form, and the code I'm about to share is step 1. What I'm trying to do is to add validation to my select elements in react. Don't know how to do it.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique. Ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet.

Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus. Auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import HelpTooltip from "@reusables/HelpTooltip";
import Select from "@reusables/Select";

const Dimension = () => {
    return (    
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 col-page">
                    <h1 className="page-heading">Create Your KLC</h1> 
                    <p>Think of a leadership dimension and area that you want to work on:</p>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-12"> 
                    <form id="form-dimension" noValidate>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <p className="form-label">Your Dimension <i className="icon-help"></i></p>
                            <Select className="form-control" required>                                    
                                <option defaultValue>Choose your option</option>
                                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>                                                           
                                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                                <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
                                <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
                            </Select>                                                                           
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <p className="form-label">Your Area <i className="icon-help"></i></p>
                            <Select className="form-control" required>                                   
                                <option defaultValue>Choose your option</option>
                                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>                                                           
                                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                                <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
                                <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
                            </Select>                                                                         
                        </div>
                        <div className="footer-buttons">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-swans-down-fill btn-back">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-tradewind-fill btn-next">Next</button>
                        </div> 
                    </form>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                           
    )
}

export default Dimension;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below library to validate your forms

https://github.com/dockwa/simple-react-validator#readme

Comment: Thanks! But I need it to be HTML5. Like how can I place this validation: https://codeburst.io/leveraging-html5-form-validation-validation-ui-in-react-validate-forms-in-2-mins-2228024ff50d to the code above?